# Is it possible to overload functions in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

I would like to know how to overload a function in scilab. It doesn't seem to be as simple as in C++. For example,

```
function [A1,B1,np1]=pivota_parcial(A,B,n,k,np)
.......//this is just an example// the code doesn't really matter
endfunction


//has less input/output variables//operates differently



function [A1,np1]=pivota_parcial(A,n,k,np)
.......//this is just an example// the code doesn't really matter
endfunction
```

thanks

Beginner in scilab ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish something like that by combining `varargin`, `varargout` and `argn()` when you implement your function. Take a look at the following example:

```
function varargout = pivota_parcial(varargin)
    [lhs,rhs] = argn();
    //first check number of inputs or outputs
    //lhs: left-hand side (number of outputs)
    //rhs: right-hand side (number of inputs)

    if rhs == 4 then
        A  = varargin(1); B = 0;
        n  = varargin(2); k = varargin(3);
        np = varargin(4);
    elseif rhs == 5 then
        A  = varargin(1); B = varargin(2);
        n  = varargin(3); k = varargin(4);
        np = varargin(5);
    else
        error("Input error message");
    end

    //computation goes on and it may depend on (rhs) and (lhs)
    //for the sake of running this code, let's just do:
    A1 = A;
    B1 = B;
    np1 = n;

    //output
    varargout = list(A1,B1,np1);
endfunction
```

First, you use `argn()` to check how many arguments are passed to the function. Then, you rename them the way you need, doing `A = varargin(1)` and so on. Notice that `B`, which is not an input in the case of 4 inputs, is now set to a constant. Maybe you actually need a value for it anyways, maybe not.

After everything is said and done, you need to set your output, and here comes the part in which using only `varargout` may not satisfy your need. If you use the last line the way it is, `varargout = list(A1,B1,np1)`, you can actually call the function with 0 and up to 3 outputs, but they will be provided in the same sequence as they appear in the `list()`, like this:

- `pivota_parcial(A,B,n,k,np);`: will run and the first output `A1` will be delivered, but it won't be stored in any variable.
- `[x] = pivota_parcial(A,B,n,k,np);`: `x` will be `A1`.
- `[x,y] = pivota_parcial(A,B,n,k,np);`: `x` will be `A1` and `y` will be `B1`.
- `[x,y,z] = pivota_parcial(A,B,n,k,np);`: `x` will be `A1`, `y` will be `B1`, `z` will be `np1`.

If you specifically need to change the order of the output, you'll need to do the same thing you did with your inputs: check the number of outputs and use that to define `varargout` for each case. Basically, you'll have to change the last line by something like the following:

```
    if lhs == 2 then
        varargout = list(A1,np1);
    elseif lhs == 3 then
        varargout = list(A1,B1,np1);
    else
        error("Output error message");
    end
```

Note that even by doing this, the ability to call this functions with 0 and up to 2 or 3 outputs is retained.

Comment: I upvoted your comment, but since I'm a newbie here it doesn't seem to make a difference. Sorry...
Thank you much! (Muito Obrigado amigo!!)

Comment: De nada. Does my answer solve you problem? If it solves it, you could accept it instead of upvoting. Click on the "V" below the vote arrows. If it doesn't help you, can you clarify it? Tell me what part doesn't work for you, or what is it your really need to to.